# ArrayList internal working

Tags: java, collections

I wanna test how the indexing work in case of arrayList. When I try to add element at a  specified index say arrlist.add(15, "shreyas"); I get an Exception "IndexOutOfBoundException".. why is that so?? I am confused. please help..!!! Thanks in advance

```
ArrayList <String> arrlist = new ArrayList <String>(20);
          arrlist.add(15, "shreyas");
          arrlist.add(18, "jp");

          for(int i=0;i<arrlist.size();i++){
                 System.out.println("Index is i="+i+" And Element is "+arrlist.get(i));
   }
```

Comment: Why don't you look at the source code of JDK?

Comment: `new ArrayList<String>(20)` - the list still starts empty, the 20 is for performance tweaking only.

Comment: Remember, `ArrayList <String>(20)` doesn't define a "size", but provides a "growth" hint to the class so when the number of elements get's close to filling the internal buffer it can resized more efficiently...

Answer (score 7):

The ArrayList can't have gaps. You can't add an element to the 15'th position if you haven't added elements to the 0 to 14 positions first.

Comment: Thanks Eran. But whats the purpose of providing arrlist.add(index, object);

Comment: Purpose is to add an element "in between" a list.

Comment: @ShreyasDeshpande It doesn't replace, it adds an element before an existing element. For replace there's a different method - `set(index,object)`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code from my JDK 8 source

```
/**
     * A version of rangeCheck used by add and addAll.
     */
    private void rangeCheckForAdd(int index) {
        if (index > size || index < 0)
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));
    }
```

It clearly shows that if you have passed your index greater than the next position assumed by ArrayList, or if your index is less than 0, it will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Purpose of this method is to add an element "in between" a list.

Comment: Thanks Akash. But whats the purpose of providing arrlist.add(index, object); when can we use it ??

Comment: It adds an element at the specified location inside the list. Why do you need that? Well, it's your logic. One case is you might need your insertions to be sorted. What would happen to the element already present on that location? This method shifts all the elements having greater index by one place, making room for new index. So, you have an empty space just to land your new element in the list. Hope it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert elements in between an ArrayList but cannot leave the spaces in between.

From ArrayList.class

```
if (index > size || index < 0)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
        "Index: "+index+", Size: "+size);
```

Answer (score 0):

As already explained by Akash.. you can not add the element at the location which is greater than current array index.
And the basic use of the add(index,object) method is, if pass index < arraylist length then the new element is added at that location an all the subsequent elements are shifted right by one location.

Hope this clarify your query

Answer (score 0):

First of all **ArrayList** maintain an internal `Object array` `Object[]`.

So as inside its an array, you can expect any behavior similar of array and   you cannot add any element  add the position greater that it size.

Yet the purpose of this `public void add(int index,E element)` is described better in the doc

`Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).`

[ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E))